# YouCompleteMe without MacVim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I've been reading about youcompleteme plugin for VIM.
The problem is, however, that I want a setup I just can move onto my other dev platforms (OpenIndiana, FreeBSD, Linux and OS X).

Wouldn't using macvim make that somewhat difficult, moving plugin from platform to platform?

Cheers

Comment: YouCompleteMe does not require MacVim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MacVim is simply a distribution of Vim for Mac OS but most of Vim plugins are compatible with the multiples versions of Vim for the different OS.

Still YouCompleteMe comports a compiled component so your question is legit to wonder if it will work on different OSes. According to the [installation section](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#installation) of the Readme of the project, YCM can be installed on OSX, Linux and FreeBSD with a plugin manager like Vundle. *(I really don't know OpenIndiana and it isn't mentioned on the Readme page so I can't say if you'll have a problem with this one)*

One point you should take care is that if you update the plugin and the compiled component has changed you'll have to recompile it but it doesn't happen that often and you should get a warning at the update.

**TL;DR** This shouldn't be an issue to use YCM on most of the common OSes but when updating remember that you might need to recompile the compiled component sometimes.